# How to set ip address correctly?

Tags: netplan, static-ip, ip-address

I apologize in advance if my english is bad

i want to ask how to set the ip address, i have written this command, and then saved ctrl + x > Y > enter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUEkH.png]

but the result doesn't match

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3tuN.jpg]

I've been working on it for 4 days but it keeps failing, I hope there's an angel here who can help me

Comment: Your YAML seems incorrect. It is missing a `renderer:` line. See https://netplan.io/examples/#using-dhcp-and-static-addressing for working examples.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Desktop or Server installation? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345281/edit), using copy/paste, not screenshots, and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `ls -al /etc/netplan` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted output also shows that the wrong address is dynamically assigned.

This means something else, besides the netplan yaml file you have shown, is configuring addresses on this interface, probably via dhcp.

If you have the `dhcpcd5` package installed on your system, you should remove it.

However, I also note that in your editor screenshot, it shows a filename of `00-installer-config.yml`.  Netplan does *not* support reading configuration from files with a `.yml` extension.  The correct extension is `.yaml`.  It is possible that the dhcp address is a result of unmodified configuration in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`, which will do dhcp by default, and the file you are editing is ignored by netplan.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem days ago. The mistakes were:

1. Not realizing the YAML file was not even read by **netplan**
2. YAML spelling & not applying the changes properly.
3. Link/ interface down

**3** is not a problem here. Let's see the rest.

Netplan only reads the **yaml** extension, not the **yml** extension So rename the file:

```
cd < access 00-... directory >
mv 00-installer-config.yml 00-installer-config.yaml
```

To see if the spelling is correct & makes sense for the parser run `sudo netplan --debug generate`. This tells any spelling or configuration error.

[It is missing a **renderer**, but that may or may not be important because it will use `networkd` as default (sorry for this technical bit).]

Next you need to run `sudo netplan apply`.

---

So:

1. Rename the file
2. Add a renderer (either networkd or network-manager)
3. Run `sudo netplan --debug generate`
   And if this is ok
4. `sudo netplan apply`

If you run `netplan help` all options described will show up for you.